# Creating an association by defining a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I'm having trouble defining this association as a has_many which I would like to do in order to get accepts_nested_attributes_for to work.

```
def work_days
  work_days = WorkDay.user_id_equals(self.user_id).company_id_equals(self.company_id)
end

accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_days
```

What would be a good solution? Is there anyway I can just say that this is an association?

-- Rails 3.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would write the `work_days` method like this:

```
def work_days
  WorkDay.where(:user_id => user_id, :company_id => company_id)
end
```

Next, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is really only for *real* associations, and so I would define a method like this:

```
def work_days=(work_day_params)
  # iterate over work_day_params and define new work day objects as required
end
```

(I may have the method name wrong)

In your form you would have something like this:

```
<% f.fields_for :work_days do |work_day| %>
  <%= render :partial => "work_days/fields", :locals => { :f => work_day } %>
<% end %>
```

In that partial you would have whatever is necessary for a work day. Once this form is submitted the params should be sent through to the controller as `params[:nest][:work_days]` and with the `work_days=` method defined on your model, it should accept them and create them just like `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does.

Comment: @fivetwentysix: No, you just pass it through as nested parameters to the parent model and the code within the model (the `work_days=` method) will take care of it. Your controller shouldn't be responsible for that.